# Como renombrar una imagen al añadirla a una carpeta y sustituirla por otra, PHP?

Tags: php

Encontré este código con el cual puedo subir y mover la imagen a la carpeta que quiero, pero además necesito que una vez se haya movido, esta sustituya la que ya existe y obtenga su mismo nombre. Por ejemplo, existe en la carpeta la imagen llamada **header.png**  y al momento de subir la nueva, sin importar su nombre esta adquiera el nombre **header.png** y borre la que que existía antes. Todo esto para que el usuario pueda actualizar el encabezado de sus reportes.

**HTML**

```
<form id="tab12" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" class="form_imagen" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <label for="">Actualizar Encabezado</label>
     <br>
     <br>
     <input type="file" name="header" id="header">
     <br>
     <br>
     <input class="consulta" type="submit" value="Subir imagen" name="Subir">
    </form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
        //Si se quiere subir una imagen
    if (isset($_POST['Subir'])) {
        //Recogemos el archivo enviado por el formulario
        $archivo = $_FILES['header']['name'];
        //Si el archivo contiene algo y es diferente de vacio
        if (isset($archivo) && $archivo != "") {
           //Obtenemos algunos datos necesarios sobre el archivo
           $tipo = $_FILES['header']['type'];
           $tamano = $_FILES['header']['size'];
           $temp = $_FILES['header']['tmp_name'];
           //Se comprueba si el archivo a cargar es correcto observando su extensión y tamaño
          if (!((strpos($tipo, "gif") || strpos($tipo, "jpeg") || strpos($tipo, "jpg") || strpos($tipo, "png")) && ($tamano < 2000000))) {
             echo '<div><b>Error. La extensión o el tamaño de los archivos no es correcta.<br/>
             - Se permiten archivos .gif, .jpg, .png. y de 200 kb como máximo.</b></div>';
          }
          else {
             //Si la imagen es correcta en tamaño y tipo
             //Se intenta subir al servidor
             if (move_uploaded_file($temp, 'Imagenes/'.$archivo)) {
                 //Cambiamos los permisos del archivo a 777 para poder modificarlo posteriormente
                 chmod('Imagenes/'.$archivo, 0777);
                 //Mostramos el mensaje de que se ha subido con éxito
                 echo '<script> alert("Se ha subido correctamente la imagen.")</script>';
             }
             else {
                //Si no se ha podido subir la imagen, mostramos un mensaje de error
                echo '<script> alert("No se pudo guardar la imagen.")</script>';
             }
           }
        }
     }

    ?>
```

Comment: Prueba a borrar primero la existente, y luego mueves la nueva

Comment: Así pude borrar la imagen antigua y sustituirla por la recién subida. Solo falta renombrarla.`unlink("./Imagenes/header.png");`

Answer (score 0):

Usa esto para remplazar el nombre:

**PHP**

```html
<?php
     move_uploaded_file($temp, 'carpeta/'.'NuevoNombre'.time()); 
?>
```

En donde dice nuevo nombre, puedes colocar el nombre que quieras, con el time(), haces que no se generen nombres repetidos y no haya problemas.

Espero haberte ayudado!

Comment: pero si la tengo la imagen en una variable?                                                        `if (move_uploaded_file($temp, 'Imagenes/'.$archivo))`

Comment: Cambias el valor a la variable antes de ponerla en el **move_uploaded_file**, o la otra forma sería **move_uploaded_file($temp, 'Imagenes/'.$archivo."agregarValor")**, o solo quitas la variable **$archivo** y la remplazas por un string.

Comment: `rename("./Imagenes/$archivo","./Imagenes/footer.png");` lo pude resolver de esta manera amigo, ahora el problema es que también debo cambiar la extensión, por que si bien con  **footer.png** cambio la extensión, por algún motivo el ffpdf me lanza un error, por ejemplo si subo una imagen en png no hay problema, me la lanza mis reportes ya modificados. Pero si subo una imagen con otra extensión, pues se sube pero me lanza error al generar los reportes, sabes como modificar la extensión?

Answer (score 0):

Para remplazar la extensión de la imagen, puedes hacerlo con preg_replace(), se usa con expresión regular, en la página oficial de php puedes encontrarlo https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php

Un ejemplo:

```
<?php 
   $imagen = "footer.png";
   $imagen = preg_replace("/png|jpg/", "jpeg", $imagen);
?>
```

Comment: sabes si hay otra forma de cambiar la extensión? Con `preg_replace()`  si me cambia la extensión, inclusive al meterme al archivo en efecto ya muestra la extensión que cambiaste, pero al generar mis reportes en **FPDF** como que no reconoce que es esa extensión sino la antigua

Comment: Puedes intentar con `imagepng($_FILES["nombre"]["tmp"], "footer.png")` avísame si te ha servido.

Comment: No logro hacer que funcione, lo agregue antes del:  `if(move_uploaded_file()`  y después del `chmod()` , segun yo esta bien `imagepng($_FILES["footer"]["tmp_name"], "footer.png");`  también probé ponerle `$temp = imagepng($_FILES["footer"]["tmp_name"], "footer.png");`

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurrió una forma para poder hacer lo que necesitas, así podrás cambiar la extensión de el archivo. Intenté de hacer el código lo más corto posible.

**EJEMPLO:**

```
**JAVASCRIPT**

const input = document.querySelector("input");

input.onchange = function(){
  const file = this.files[0];
  const read = new FileReader();
  read.onload = ()=>{
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "archivo.php");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "aplication/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send("file="+read.result);
  }
  read.readAsDataURL(file);
}

 **PHP**

<?php 

  $file = $_POST['file'];

  $array1 = explode(";", $file);
  $array2 = explode(",", $array1[1]);
  $decode = base64_decode($array2);
  $ruta = "carpeta/"."footer"."png";

  file_put_contents($ruta, $decode);

 ?>
```

Espero haberte ayudado!